# issue with the_permalink

Tags: permalinks

I'm working on a site using a child theme, and running into an issue with the blog permalink not showing the full post, but rather looping the abstract.

If I change the template, it works fine, so the issue seems to be in the child template somewhere.

I removed `category.php`, `single.php` and `functions.php` from the child theme to allow it to default to the parent, but that didn't work. I also deactivated all plugins to see if the issue is there. Still no success.

The problem seems to be with the `<?php the_permalink() ?>` line, but I have no idea where else to look. Any ideas? Here's the URL:

http://airtechsite.staging.wpengine.com/category/blog/

Comment: Can you ellaborate on what you mean by 'looping the abstract'? The permalink appears to work fine looking at your site, it's the post template doing this, the permalink is nothing to do with this and a complete red herring that you should avoid.

Comment: I agree. Unless you expect your post URIs to have a different structure, check single.php

Comment: Oh, to elaborate, I'm guessing single.php has `get_template_part('content', 'blog')` rather than `get_template_part('content', 'post')`

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved. The problem was in the content.php file. I accidentally modified...

```
the_content( sprintf(
    __( 'Continue reading %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentythirteen' ),
    the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false )
) );
```

to:

```
the_abstract( sprintf(
    __( 'Continue reading %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentythirteen' ),
    the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false )
) );
```

when what I needed was:

```
<?php if ( is_tag() || is_search() || is_category() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>

    <div class="entry-summary">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```